# Contentfull Api filter nested collection

Tags: javascript, graphql, contentful, contentful-api

I have been using [Contenfull](https://www.contentful.com/) to create a custom app.
Now the problem that I'm having is I can not see how can I query a nested collection

I have the following entry

```
query cfPageList(
  $contentfulLocale: String
  $entryId: String!
  $preview: Boolean = false
) {
  cfPageList(id: $entryId, locale: $contentfulLocale, preview: $preview) {
    sys {
      id
    }
    categoryListCollection {
      options: items {
        value: value
        label: itemName
        disabled: disabled
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to query all the CategoryList that have `disabled` to `false`

I tried with
`cfPageList(id: $entryId, locale: $contentfulLocale, preview: $preview, where: { disabled: false })`

Tried with

`cfPageList(id: $entryId, locale: $contentfulLocale, preview: $preview, where: { categoryListCollection: { disabled: false } })`

But none of it works, do any of you guys have any idea how it should work, or if it is possible to do it with Contentfull.

Answer (score -1):

You should try filter items

```js
categoryListCollection {
  options: items(where: {disabled: false}) {
    value: value
    lebel: itemName
    disabled: disabled
  }
}
```

- or

```js
categoryListCollection(where: {disabled: false}) {
  options: items {
    value: value
    lebel: itemName
    disabled: disabled
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not working, since Contentfull Api does not have these options